# How long should the first boot take with CyanogenMod 9?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-defy

On [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1432100) they say "Frst boot will take some time...", but I've waited 25 minutes and my phone has not finished booting. About how long does the first boot usually take?

Comment: If you've waited 25 minutes it's probably not booting properly. I generally wouldn't wait longer than 5 minutes or so, though I doubt there's any definite timeframe to cite.

Comment: @eldarerathis I'm trienging to reboot now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally below 5 minutes, anything over 10 minutes is probably considered a wrong flash. Read the instructions given by the developer and than try again.
If It still doesn't work as for help in the roms thread ask they will be better suited to help with specific questions about your rom than us.